# Share C++ object instances with QML

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qml

I have a logical business in C++11 and I need to expose and SHARE some C++ QObjetcts with QML UI.

I use a fake-singleton approach to expose these objects with a lambda and static variable :

```
static classname *static_pointer=&non_singleton_QObject_instance;

qmlRegisterSingletonType<classname>("ClassName", 1, 0, "ClassName", 
     [](QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) -> QObject * {
             Q_UNUSED(engine) Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine) 
             return static_pointer;
 });
```

It works fine, but when application exits I get errors, because
C++ objects are destroyed by `QGuiApplication` before `QQmlApplicationEngine` destructor.

When `QQmlApplicationEngine`  tries to access these fake-singleton objects in his destructor, I get a crash.

I can solve it skiping QQmlApplicationEngine with an exit(0) call, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to store in a singleton object the QQmlContext

then, register objects

```
SingletonContext::instance()->Context()->setContextProperty("Plclink",&m_link );
```

the problem is tha I can access to functions from QTCreator, and Q_ENUM variables are not registered

example:
with setContextProperty

```
onActivated: {
                    Plclink.setvaluechanged(Plclink.DB_PROGRAMA ,Plclink.DBW_ENCURSO,index )
                }
```

fails (Q_ENUM DB_PROGRAMA  is always 0)

but with

```
static plclink *slink=&m_link;
qmlRegisterSingletonType<plclink>("Plclink", 1, 0, "Plclink", [](QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) -> QObject * {
    Q_UNUSED(engine) Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)
            return slink;
});
```

and

```
  import Plclink 1.0
```

works fine